# Not able to replace a text in PDF using PDFBox 2.0.2

Tags: java, pdf

**My requirements**

1)    I need to identify a particular text pattern
2)  Then replace that
   text pattern with pre-defined text-value with the same format of text
   pattern, such as font, font colour, bold  …

3)  I am able to identify
   the text, replace that text with predefined values, But writing to
   PDF is failing.

**I tried the following 2 appraches to write to PDF**

1)  By Overriding writeString(String string, List textPositions)of PDFTextStripper

2)  By using  cosArray.add(new COSString(replacedField)); or cosArray.set(…)

**Results for approach 1 - By Overriding writeString**

The pdf generated by this code is not getting opened in PDF. I am able to open in word, But there is no format of original text.

**Results for approach 2 - By using  cosArray.add  or cosArray.set(…)**
I am seeing only boxes in generated  PDF .

**Code for approach 1 - By Overriding writeString**

```
public void rewrite(String templatePDFPath) throws IOException {

    PDDocument document = null;

    Writer pdfWriter = null;

    try {

        File templateFile = new File(templatePDFPath);
        document = PDDocument.load(templateFile);

        this.setSortByPosition(true);
        this.setStartPage(0);
        this.setEndPage(document.getNumberOfPages());

        pdfWriter = new PrintWriter(Utils.getFilePathWithTimeStamp(templatePDFPath).toString());

        this.writeText(document, pdfWriter);

    } finally {
        if (document != null) {
            document.close();
        }

        if (null != pdfWriter)
            pdfWriter.close();

        // if (null != pdfWriter)
        // pdfWriter.close();

    }
}

protected void writeString(String string, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException {

    for (int i = 0; i < textPositions.size(); i++) {
        TextPosition text = textPositions.get(i);

        String currentCharcter = text.getUnicode();
        // System.out.println("String[" + text.getXDirAdj() + "," + //
        // text.getYDirAdj() + " fs=" + text.getFontSize() // + " xscale=" +
        // text.getXScale() + " height=" + // text.getHeightDir() + "
        // space=" // +
        // text.getWidthOfSpace() + " width=" + text.getWidthDirAdj() + //
        // "]" +
        // currentCharcter);

    }
    String replacedString = replaceFields(string.trim());

    if (!(string.equals(replacedString))) {
        System.out.println("Field " + string + " is replaced by value " + replacedString);
        // super.writeString(replacedString, textPositions);
        super.writeString(replacedString);
    }

}
```

**Code for approach 2 -  By using  cosArray.add  or cosArray.set(…)**

```
public List<String> replaceFieldsInCosArray(COSArray cosArray) {
    List<String> replacedStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    String stringsOfCOSArray = "";

    for (int cosArrayIndex = 0; cosArrayIndex < cosArray.size(); cosArrayIndex++) {
        Object cosObject = cosArray.get(cosArrayIndex);

        if (cosObject instanceof COSString) {
            COSString cosString = (COSString) cosObject;
            stringsOfCOSArray += cosString.getString();
        }
    }
    stringsOfCOSArray = stringsOfCOSArray.trim();



    //cosArray.clear();



        String replacedField = this.replaceFields(stringsOfCOSArray);
        System.out.println("cosText:" + stringsOfCOSArray + ":replacedField:" + replacedField);

        cosArray.add(new COSString(replacedField));

        if (!stringsOfCOSArray.equals(replacedField)) {
            replacedStrings.add(replacedField);
        }
```

**strong text**

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35420609/pdfbox-2-0-rc3-find-and-replace-text

Answer (score 0):

> 1) By Overriding writeString(String string, List textPositions)of PDFTextStripper

`PDFTextStripper` is a tool for extraction of **plain text**. Thus, it is not surprising that your output cannot be opened as pdf. Furthermore, word can open it because word recognises it as plain text and opens it as such.

> 2) By using cosArray.add(new COSString(replacedField)); or cosArray.set(…)

It is not really clear what you mean here. In particular, which `cosArray` are you talking about?

One might assume you mean the parameter of the **TJ** operator but there are multiple reasons against that assumption:

- the **TJ** operator is but one of the many text showing operators and the only one accepting am array argument; thus, you would look at only a few of the operators in question;
- your code would assume that the whole *text pattern* you try to identify is drawn by the same operation; why should it?
- you seem to assume that `cosString.getString()` returns something intelligible; unfortunately that is not the case in general, merely if the fonts in question usesome standard encoding which had been becoming less and less common;
- furthermore, you assume that the glyphs for your replacement text are contained in the font of the replaced text. Why should they? Embedded font subsets have become more and more common...

Thus, what do you actually mean here?

---

That all being said, if you happen to work merely with naively built pdfs, you might want to look at the answer to the question @Tilmann pointed you to. There is a small set of pdfs that code may work for.

If your pdfs happen to be more sophisticated,  though, even describing the approach would be beyond the scope of a single stackoverflow answer.

---

By the way, your requirements are not well defined, in particular

> replace that text pattern with pre-defined text-value with the same format of text pattern, such as font, font colour, bold …

If the predefined text has three letters, the replacement has two letters, and the found occurrence has the first glyph in red, the second in green, and the third in blue, how should the two replacement glyphs be drawn using those three colors?