# While creating the text layer for scanned PDF edit the text without messing up the page looks?

Tags: python, pdf, ocr, pdfbox

While creating the text(getting text using OCR) layer for scanned PDF edit(because OCR is giving wrong text) the text without messing up the page looks?

[ocrmypdf](https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) is doing best job to create textlayer(able to search scanned PDF) and giving PDF/A standard documents(without messing any page UI). It's using Tesseract ocr to detect text, but some times the Tesseract is giving wrong detected text. So I want enable user to change that text and complete the creation of PDF.

Example [PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mdtazw6rRkIhuNXkBA_kKt03DoLygvY1/view?usp=sharing) which is OCRis not working properly. So want to update the ocr detected text before rendering into PDF.

Solution need like , Change in source code of ocrmypdf or update text using PDFBOX both works for me.

Example:

OCRMYPDF input [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bdgN-569x5YotQLlsGdDHy2VKG96aJex/view?usp=sharing)

OCRMYPDF output [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10YYeHD3BkrNb26PcAuvHkjxZnkQXc0hI/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What exactly do you expect? How shall a *user change that text*? Do you want to create some GUI in which they can somehow influence the text underneath the scan? Or do you want to give them only the recognized text pieces with coordinates and they can change them? This will give rise to how your ocrmypdf/pdfbox solution needs to work.

Comment: @mkl  I want to give them only the recognized text pieces with coordinates and  then they can change them? this is what exactly I need.

Comment: Well, if you look at the generated content stream text drawing instructions, they appear fairly easy to manipulate: an UTF-16-ish font encoding and each piece of text positioned by its own **Tm** instruction. Nonetheless it would be better if one could hook into ocrmypdf right before the creation of those text drawing instructions, so the text is embedded as desired from the start. Unfortunately I don't know ocrmypdf or tesseract internals and cannot help there.

Comment: ok, So I will try to manipulate text after text layer creation. can you please put some example code How can I manipulate based on positions using PDFBOX?

Comment: You need to extract with layout. I've been looking at https://forum.xpdfreader.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=42250 Also visual scan and maybe run a spelling checker over results before committing text layer. FreeOCR is pretty good.